# Is there a function to transpose matrices (lists of lists) in python? if rows not equal column

Tags: python, function, matrix

Is there a function to convert matrices in python? example `[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]` => ans : `[1,4,7],[2,5,8]`

Comment: I would call this operation "transpose" rather than "convert" (which could mean anything).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function, like this

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print zip(*l)
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Comment: what a clever use of zip and argument expansion

Comment: @caoy People used to call this as argument unpacking :)

Comment: lol, thanks, i knew i shouldn't just invent names :P

Comment: @ thefourtheye if rows not equal columns. example [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,0,11,12]] output [[1,5,9],[2,6,0],[3,7,11],[4,8,12]]

Comment: @pukluk It will still work. Please try that yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your program, you may want to use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
In [1]: m = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

In [2]: m
Out[2]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [3]: m.T
Out[3]: 
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Comment: if rows not equal columns. example [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,0,11,12]] output [[1,5,9],[2,6,0],[3,7,11],[4,8,12]]

Comment: This will still work in numpy.